# Apportable error: undefined reference to 'OBJC_CLASS_$_FBSession'

Tags: android, ios, apportable

Setup is according to given in [Github/FacebookSDK](https://github.com/apportable/ApportableFacebookSDK) and every thing is just fine,

but when run command **apportable build** it gives error like this

```
.../Source/AppDelegate.m:function L_OBJC_CLASSLIST_REFERENCES_$_125: error: undefined reference to 'OBJC_CLASS_$_FBSession'
.../Source/EndGame.m:function L_OBJC_CLASSLIST_REFERENCES_$_125: error: undefined reference to 'OBJC_CLASS_$_FBSession'
.../Source/EndGame.m:function L_OBJC_CLASSLIST_REFERENCES_$_147: error: undefined reference to 'OBJC_CLASS_$_FBRequest'
.../Source/EndGame.m:function L_OBJC_CLASSLIST_REFERENCES_$_257: error: undefined reference to 'OBJC_CLASS_$_FBRequestConnection'
```

what i am doing wrong ?
thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apportable starter SDK version does not support Facebook ios SDK compilation. You must have an [Indie Version](http://www.apportable.com/pricing) to have support for social media SDKs.

[image]